# Bootstrap: what is wrong in my bootstrap code

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

What is the problem in this code, it is supposed to be responsive on my tablet but it is not, I have used 12 column for two divs, so the third should be below them in a new row, but when I check my index.html on my tablet I find them all in one row, what is the problem in this code.

```
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "demo.css">  
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 ">Bootstrap Tutorial</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6  ">Bootstrap Tutorial</div>
         <div class="col-xs-4  ">Bootstrap Tutorial</div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">click</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="demo.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Check the snippet editor and ask yourself why the red text in the HTML source view shows up. `<div class="container"></div>` should be `<div class="container">`

Comment: sorry i think i have edited it, it is the first time to post a question here

Comment: can you confirm you are using V3 of V4 of bootstrap ?

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal why editing the question and including V4 of bootstrap ? why you assumed it V4 and not V4 ? you completely change the question and made it irrelevant

Comment: @TemaniAfif I didn't add anything. I just formatted the question. The libraries were already added by the user :)

Comment: i use bootstrap v4

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal i see, it was hidden and not visible on the history edits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `col-xs-*` classes don't exist in Bootstrap 4 (anymore).

Replace all those with the corresponding `col-*` classes.

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#grid-system

### Also important:

Your question and code suggest that you are **misinterpreting the expected behavior**.

So, I suggest you study the documentation on this page here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

The following code snippet might give you a better idea of how it works:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.row>[class^=col-] {
padding-top: .75rem;
padding-bottom: .75rem;
background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}
</style>
   
<div class="container">
    <h2>Medium ('md') breakpoint:</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">Bootstrap Tutorial 1</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Bootstrap Tutorial 2</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Bootstrap Tutorial 3</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container mt-3">
   <h2>Large ('lg') breakpoint:</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">Bootstrap Tutorial 1</div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">Bootstrap Tutorial 2</div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">Bootstrap Tutorial 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this is good advice, it fails to address the invalid HTML aspect.

Comment: @connexo That's not the main cause of the problem here because modern browsers have gotten very good at dealing with invalid HTML. The main cause is two-fold and is described in my answer.

Comment: Still `.row` will not be inside `.container`  which is obviously what OP intended.

Comment: @connexo The `.row` *is* inside the `.container` in the code I copied from OP's post into my code editor.

Comment: so col-xs-* was removed from bootstrap 4 and now i can use just col - * really thank you i was trying since hours now

Comment: @SaherElgendy You simply replace all instances of `col-xs-` with `col-` because that's the replacement for the old `col-xs-*` class group. But again, you seem to be misinterpreting how it should behave for responsive behavior. You should really read that page from the second link in my answer.

Comment: where there is in the question that it's Bootstrap V4 ?

Comment: no there is not, check the edit history .. someone edited the question to include bootstrap V4

Comment: @WebDevBooster i did that already but it says that i have less than 15 points reputations

Comment: @SaherElgendy But are you actually using Bootstrap 4 or Bootstrap 3?

Comment: @WebDevBooster i use bootstrap 4

Comment: @SaherElgendy It would be better if you posted a separate question with the new code. Because this is a different question now and we are not supposed/not allowed to handle different questions this way.

Comment: @WebDevBooster  ok now i can not ask a new question before 3 days

Comment: @SaherElgendy Try the code snippet I just added to my answer and see if that works for you.

Comment: @WebDevBooster really thank you for that, my problem still in tablet, when i changed all lgs in your code to sms, it did not change, just one row in contrary to what i expected(two opposite divs and one below them)

Comment: This might have something to do with your tablet in this case. Try to clear the cache in your tablet's browser. Or simply just create a brand new file/file name and paste all my code into that and try that.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to keep up with your edits from your original post.  Anyhow I move all your `<script>` and `<link>` tags into the `<head>`.  I changed your `col-xs-*` to `col-*`.

**EDIT** : Thanks to Temani Afif, I updated my post.  Also, I presumed he was using BS4 and not BS3 as I was looking at an earlier revision of the post.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-6">Bootstrap Tutorial</div>
      <div class="col col-6">Bootstrap Tutorial</div>
      <div class="col col-4">Bootstrap Tutorial</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: we don't need the third column in a separate row ...you can have more than 12 in one row ... so what you said is wrong

Comment: ok thank you but why we need to create a new row, they are all 12 column so any extra column will go below, am i missing something???

Comment: thank you for updating it,  yes i also updated it to that, but it produces 3 divs in 3 different rows below each others??

Comment: @SaherElgendy  So what do you see when you run the code snippet?  It works as expected for me.

Comment: it works like yours in pc browser but not in tablet, sm is for tablet, i expect it to work as two divs in one row and one below them but in my tablet they are below each others

Comment: @SaherElgendy  I created a codepen [**here**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQQvPy) and viewed it on my phone.  They display as 3 columns side by side.

Comment: @SaherElgendy  Updated my post.  I'm using `col-*` instead of `col-sm-*`.

Comment: @user9263373 thank you but why you did not use sm, is not sm supposed to work on tablet?, this is my question about

Comment: @SaherElgendy  As was posted by other users `col-xs-*` was replaced by `col-*` in [**Bootstrap 4**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options) for breakpoints <576px.

Comment: @user9263373  thank you , i was asking about why sm is not working also, was it replaced also??

Comment: @SaherElgendy refer to the documentation link provided in my comment above.  `col-sm-*` still exists but it's for breakpoints ≥576px.

Comment: @user9263373 yes this is exactly my question, it does not work on tablet as expected